# rails 3 complex url, harmful or harmless?. Could it be fixed?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, url, parameters

The following url is formed in my rails application,

```
 "http://example.com/filter/filters?binding_id=1>1&escape=false&filter_type=publisher_id&from_pagination=0&genre_id=0>57&order=3&page=8&publisher_id=3>160&query=books&search_case=products&sub_category_id=1&tree_filter_id=115&utf8=%E2%9C%93&view_name=generic2d4e4c5333133cd814a2cb102571e4dc"
```

**Is this OK?**

If I alter any one parameter in the above URL the code crashes with error which is reasonable since the "filter" controller's "filters" action needs all of these in the "params" hash.

**Is this fine?. Is there a way to handle this?**

Please advice.

Comment: what are you trying to achieve? Maybe posting the controller code would help understand.  Just like that, it smell ;-)

Comment: Controller code is very abstract I mean it calls methods from application controller and application controller is like 800 lines. Im not trying to achieve anything. I just felt bad looking at this URL's size. Is it fine to have such urls?. Thats all i want to know. My applications is working very well!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I may be wrong, but it looks like you are trying to pass too much params in the URL.

It look like you are using an HTTP GET to pass data to your controller instead of HTTP POST.

With the POST, you could use a an HTML FORM to pass your data to the controller and your url would be a lot cleaner.

Comment: You are not wrong. You are right!. Im using a get method to pass data to my controller and as you suggested, I can use a form's hidden field tag and post method to make my urls cleaner. Thanks for that answer. My question now is, please confirm if I can achieve everything with POST that I could with GET.

Comment: Alright now I gotcha!... If I use POST, and then I copy paste that URL onto a different browser, then I wont hit the right page, right?

Comment: Of Course, actually it is a best practice in web dev. to only use GET when you actually wanna read data from the server and POST when you want to write/update data to your server app.  And this is true not only for Rails but for Java .NET PHP etc.

Comment: Yes, the name suggests that, GET(read).. POST(write).. Whoever named it made so self explanatory, had a good time revising the basics of web applications. I will keep this URL itself. Now I know, its importance.